# Kubernetes Pod with multiple containers can't connect to each other (DNS issue?!)

Tags: kubernetes, dns, google-kubernetes-engine

For our CI pipeline I setup a Kubernetes pod config (see below). There is one issue that the php app can't connect to the mysql container because it can't resolve the host "mysql".
Error message:

```
mysqli_connect(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known
```

pod  config:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
spec:
  containers:
  - name: php
    image: docker.pkg.github.com/foo-org/bar-php/bar-php:latest
  - name: nginx
    image: docker.pkg.github.com/foo-org/bar-nginx/bar-nginx:latest
    command:
    - cat
    tty: true
  - name: mysql
    image: docker.pkg.github.com/foo-org/bar-mysql/bar-mysql:latest
    env:
    - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
      value: bazz
    ports:
    - containerPort: 3306
    readinessProbe:
      tcpSocket:
        port: 3306
      initialDelaySeconds: 5
    tty: true
  imagePullSecrets:
  - name: ci-gh-registry
```

This runs in GKE but I guess this doesn't make a difference?

Any ideas why and how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

provide host as `127.0.0.1` or `localhost` instead of `mysql` containers in a pod communicate over localhost

Comment: Thanks, that was a bit unexpected, there are a couple of tutorials which don't use localhost.